# Recursive union definition in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, unions

I wanted to make something like a binary search tree for mapping addresses to `Page *`s (except it was actually hexadecimal, and the address is implied by the structure itself), so:

```
typedef union Map Map;
union Map {
    Map (*ps)[16];
    Page *p;
};
```

This makes perfect sense, logically (a union `Map` containing either a pointer to a `Page` or a pointer to an array of 16 `Map`s), but gcc errors at the `ps` declaration with `array type has incomplete element type`, so I guess this kind of recursive definition is not allowed in C.

Is there any way to do this without using tricks like pointer aliasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C 2018 6.7.6.2 1 specifies the constraints for array declarators. It says, in part:

> The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type.

In `Map (*ps)[16]`, the `(*ps)[16]` is a *declarator* as shown in the grammar at 6.7.6 1. Since it is an array declarator, it is subject to the rules in 6.7.6.2, and therefore the element type must be complete. This is true even though the ultimate type being declared is a pointer.

As noted in a comment, you can declare `Map *ps` instead. If this is unsatisfactory because then pointer arithmetic on `ps` works in units of `Map` instead of `Map [16]`, an alternative could be to define `typedef struct Map16 Map16;` before the union, then `Map16 *ps;` inside the union, and then `struct Map16 { Map element[16]; }` after the union. That will make pointer arithmetic on `ps` work in the desired units (supposing the implementation does not pad the structure, which would be unusual), although it does make you use an extra `.element` when referencing elements.

In considering why `Map *ps` is accepted while `Map (*ps)[16]` is not, we can see that both declare pointers to incomplete types, and so it is not the completeness of the pointed-to type that distinguishes them but merely this rule in the C standard. It may be that the rule in 6.7.6.2 1 could have been modified to permit `Map (*ps)[16]`, as it does not appear the compiler needs complete information about the pointed-to type at that point.

Comment: @4386427 What conclusion? The conclusion is given in the question itself. This answer is formally explaining why.

Comment: Yet, I believe the OP have asked something else.

Comment: @4386427: No, my conclusion is that a particular rule in the C standard applies, which both explains the behavior and gives people correct information to reason with about similar situations.  Your “conclusion” was that some sort of ill-defined information lack or sufficiency explained the behavior, which is false.

Comment: @4386427 It is a *pointer* to an incomplete type, which by itself does not have to be incomplete.

Comment: @4386427 Yes, which was just proven by this standard citation. But the fact the compiler is considering it incomplete was clear from the question itself. So the discussion was about *why* the pointer to an incomplete structure is complete but a pointer to an incomplete array is not. The rationale for this specific case is still arguable though, but well, that's what the standard is defining.

Comment: @4386427: The implication that because the type is incomplete the code is illegal is false, as is proven by the fact that we can declare pointers to other incomplete types, such as `struct NeverDeclared`. **The completeness of the pointed-to type has no bearing on whether the declaration is valid.** Pointers **may** be declared to incomplete types. C permits that. It is not the **pointer** that is the problem. It is a rule about **arrays**. The rule does not apply if an array is not present (`struct NeverDeclared *ps` is allowed) and does apply if an array but no pointer is present.

Comment: @4386427: It does not matter what the pointer points to because there is no constraint on the pointed-to types. The rules for declaring pointers are in C 2018 6.7.6.1.

Comment: @4386427: To further disprove your information hypothesis, observe that `struct Map16 *ps` is accepted in spite of the fact that `Map16` is later defined to contain a `Map [16]`. This `ps` points to a structure which ultimately has all the needs of an array of 16 `Map`, but the compiler does not have that information at the time `ps` is declared, yet it accepts it. Therefore, it is not a lack of information that determines acceptance or non-acceptance. It is the rules in the C standard.